# Creating new Thread to update JLabel and setIcon() in said separate Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, user-interface, updating

Trying to get an image from another application sending an array of bytes through socket, translating it to a `BufferedImage` and setting a `JLabel` in the GUI that updates every 3 seconds.

I tried looking it up on forums but questions regarding graphical update are recurrent to me and I never seem to get it right -- there's at least 6 update methods in java for graphical interface and every one I tried won't work.

I know the problem isn't in the connection to the client because I can easily save the image I receive with `ImageIO.write()` and it updates every 3 seconds to the image I was expecting to receive. I just can't have Java updating the `JLabel` correctly without having to go to forums and ask people. Such a complex task I guess. Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/95nMGLvZ. I am doing this project in Netbeans so there's a lot of stuff in there that is unnecessary to read as it does not directly relate to the problem.

I think the answer lies in creating a separate thread to update my `JLabel` from the ever-changing `BufferedImage` that is received from the `ObjectInputStream`. Anyone mind giving me a hand at this? What is better for my code? `SwingWorker`, `Threading` (wtf is setDaemon(flag)?), `Runnable`, `Timer`, `invokeLater`? Tried all of this. Not correctly apparently.

EDIT1:
Tried your answer immibis:

`public void startRunning() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(666, 10);
            connection = server.accept();
            networkStatus("Connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            Thread thr = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            thr.start();
            System.out.println(!connection.isInputShutdown());
            while (connection.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    byte[] byteImage = (byte[]) input.readObject();
                    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage);
                    final BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(in);
                    jLabel_screen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
                    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.jpg"));
                    System.out.println("i'm working");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SpyxServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }
    }`

It does not work. It says `byte[] byteImage = (byte[]) input.readObject();` line has a `NullPointerException`. The only value that can be null is the return from readObject(), meaning either the input was not initialized correctly or the connection is not synchronized. I hope it's the first option because I wouldn't know how to handle the last.

EDIT2:

Tried your answer blazetopher:

`public void startRunning() throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(666, 10);
        try {
            connection = server.accept();
            networkStatus("Connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                try {
                    byte[] byteImage = (byte[]) input.readObject();
                    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage);
                    final BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(in);
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {//<-----------
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            jLabel_screen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
                        }
                    });
                    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test.jpg"));
                    System.out.println("i'm working");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SpyxServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (EOFException eofException) {
            networkStatus("Connection Closed.    :(");
        } finally {
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        }
    }`

Using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` didn't work either. At least the program runs and can even save the image but still can't update the JLabel. Am I running out of options here?

EDIT3:
Tried Jordan's code:

`@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(biGlobal, 0, 0, null);
    }`

The GUI kind of crashed and was "drawing" the components just when I had my mouse cursor hovering it. When I started the code, it did not crashed (+1) but it did not draw anything, even when I try to hover the cursor into where the BufferedImage should be painted. Maybe I should add `revalidate()` or `repaint` after calling the Overwritten `paint(getGraphics())` inside the `startRunning()` method?

EDIT4: the `while(true)` that the code is actually in may be the problem but when I use a SwingTimer it gets out of sync with the client and crashes after first cycle. Any alternatives to this?

Comment: You cannot update the JLabel from a new thread; all GUI stuff has to happen on the GUI thread. You can, however, read from the socket on a new thread.

Comment: So if I try readObject() from another thread and in the same method receive and convert the byte[] to BufferedImage (supposedly in the same Thread as the GUI runs) I can update the JLabel? I'll try and report back. Thanks for the answer immibis!

Comment: You could use a Swing Timer, but a SwingWorker would probably be a better choice, but a runnable example would be helpful to better understand what it is you're actually doing

Comment: @MadProgrammer where and which would you add these in the code as it is? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So, from your code, something else is sending you images?  Is this why you're acting as the "server"?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you have a producer/consumer pattern.  Something is producing images and something wants to consume images.  Normally, the consumer would wait on the producer to tell it something has been produced, but in this case, we can use a observer pattern instead, having the producer notify the consumer that something was been produced (instead of waiting for it)

We need someway for the producer to communicate with the consumer...

```
public interface PictureConsumer {
    public void newPicture(BufferedImage img);
}
```

You would create an implementation of this in your UI code, this would then set the `icon` property of the `JLabel`

Now, we need something to produce the images...

```
public class PictureProducer extends SwingWorker<Object, BufferedImage> {

    private PictureConsumer consumer;

    public PictureProducer(PictureConsumer consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<BufferedImage> chunks) {
        // Really only interested in the last image
        BufferedImage img = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        consumer.newPicture(img);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        /*
         This whole setup worries me. Why is this program acting as the 
         server?  Why aren't we pooling the image producer?         
         */
        try (ServerSocket server = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(666, 10)) {
            try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
                try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
                    // Using `while (true)` is a bad idea, relying on the fact
                    // that an exception would be thrown when the connection is closed is
                    // a bad idea.
                    while (!socket.isClosed()) {
                        // Generally, I'd discourage using an ObjectInputStream, this 
                        // is just me, but you could just as easily read directly from
                        // the ByteArrayInputStream...assuming the sender was sending
                        // the data as a byte stream ;)
                        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
                        try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
                            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bis);
                            publish(img);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image Producer has failed: " + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

You can a reverse example of this (where some server is producing images and a client is consuming them) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495165/i-get-only-one-image-while-transferring-in-a-loop-over-a-socket-in-java/26498434#26498434)

Answer (score 0):

To update your label, you want to ensure you're using the EDT thread, so use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` from the code where you're receiving the BufferedImage (which would ideally be in a separate "worker" thread:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Update your label here
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm gonna try it and report back in a few minutes. Thank you for your answer. I've read that if you block the EDT thread your GUI is gonna freeze indefinitely because that is the thread that runs the GUI, is this true?

Also why not use a new Thread instead of invokeLater? And since we're at it, why is it necessary to give a Runnable as a parameter to an invokeLater method?

Comment: That can occur, or you can get errors.  Using the SwingUtilities method prevents this by putting the Runnable onto the [EventQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) so it can be run by the EDT thread, thereby avoiding deadlock and/or errors.

Comment: Tried it. Posting the second edit right now. At least the app didn't crash this time whereas with immibis' answer it did. But it also did not update the JLabel.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are attempting to accomplish.there might be a better way all together.
For example replace the `JLabel` with a `JPanel` then use that `JPanel` paint method

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(Img, xcord, ycord, null);
}
```

Then make that `JPanel` implement runnable and do your updates in that run method.

JPanel class

```
public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel{

private BufferedImage img;

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D G2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    G2D.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

}

public void setImg(BufferedImage img) {
    this.img = img;
}
```

}

then make sure this panel is visible from wherever you wish to call its methods.
this will look something like this

```
GraphicsPanel graphicsPanel = new GraphicsPanel();
    boolean running;
    BufferedImage srcImage;

    public void run(){  
        while(running){

            graphicsPanel.setImg(srcImage);
            graphicsPanel.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to receive an image over the internet from a client that sent the image as a byte array to my IP and a predefined port. From my point of view JLabel and JPanel are both GUI components, shouldn't the problem emerge the same way? It seems like masking a problem to me.

Comment: Well one benefit of using a paint component is you can draw the buffered image directly to the component without converting it to a  image icon. So weather or not it solves the problem it is better practice. you will double the speed of your application implementing this change. Then try troubleshooting from there

Comment: Oh I see. I did not know you could draw directly on the GUI's JFrame. Thanks! I'll try that and report back. I think that really might work. If it doesn't work I'll try and use invokeLater and if that doesn't work either I'll try creating a new Thread with that code.

Comment: When I get to my computer (in an hour or so) I'll edit my answer to include more code. I can't stand writing code with autocorrect on my phone :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is driving me insane for over a week now I think. I only come to forums when I'm completely out of ideas. Thanks for the time. I tried the code and I'm not sure I put it in the right place or maybe I'm just calling it wrong. Posting the edit now.

Comment: Make sure you're not calling the "paint" method call "repaint"

Comment: Shouldn't I Override the repaint() method then?

Comment: No, The method "repaint" does some background work and then calls "paint".

Comment: Calling paint directly will skip over essential code and the result can be quite glitchy.

Comment: I see. I did what you said and still ended up having the "quite glitchy result".

Comment: It's 2AM where I am I need to go to sleep now. I'll test this command in about 10 hours and report back.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing this wrong but did not work quite as I expected. I thought of another way of facing this problem but requires a big change to the code. If it doesn't work, I'll keep working on your solution and report back when I'm done.